# Close SSH connection

Tags: ssh, macos, terminal

I'm using Mac's Terminal App and I know how to connect to an external server via ssh (`ssh -l username domain.com`). But how do I *close* the connection once I'm done? Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

On the terminal window, you'll simply need to type "exit". It looks like this;

```
[username@mail0 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to [IPADDRESS] closed.
```

Answer (score 12):

When I'm on a remote server via ssh this often wont give the desired result. Especially when working with `screen` remote on a session that I want to continue some time later. `Exit` would close the screen session. What works instead is to these three buttons / characters in a row:

```
Enter ~ .
```

(including the period at the end)

Answer (score 8):

Just close the window or press Ctrl-D, which will terminate the session.